# How to access a computer on the local network that is not pingable

Tags: networking

I am trying to access a local (windows) machine on my network but this is not possible.
Even when I ping using the local address it is not returning any packets.
The only ping that is working is when I am pinging the internet ip address of that machine but this is not enough since I want to access a service that is running on that machine at port 8080.
I even cannot access the router since I am a guest in that house.
Any ideas?

Can a virtual machine on the mac of the other windows computer be a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Does ping work or not? You say both in your question.

Comment: `nmap -P0 -p8080 192.168.1.3`  <-- does that show anything? the -P0 is for when you can't ping it. -p8080 is port 8080 and that 192.168.1.3, change that for whatever IP

Comment: @Steve He actually said in his question within the first 3 lines, that it works for the public IP but not the private IP. What do you want him to say to your general question of does ping work. He said where it does work and where it doesn't work. So I don't see why you write "Does ping work or not? You say both in your question". He said fairly clearly, though it's a strange thing.

Comment: I guess the part I was confused about was "pinging the internet ip address from that machine". "That machine" = machine trying to access. My mistake.

Comment: -1 You did not say that you wanted to make it pingable. You can still access a service even if you can't ping the IP. What you -said- was   "I want to access a service that is running on that machine at port 8080."

Comment: Ping is the first command you try when you want to see if a computer anywhere in the world is accessible.So I thought that this machine was not accessible at all because of the router.As I learned today a machine may not return a ping because of the windows firewall.There is no reason to give negative points my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your computer firewall is blocking the port. If you're using Windows Firewall, follow those steps:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html

EDIT:

You can enable icmp too to ping the computer:

http://www.sysprobs.com/enable-ping-reply-windows-7

You're talking about a house router, if you are pinging the internet address of any computer in the house, which should all be the same, it's the router that is answering you.

Comment: Such an amazing answer!Thank you so much my friend!I can access the service using the local ip now (192.168.x.xxx:8080)

Comment: out of interest, do you know if it blocks outgoing ping by default? and incoming by default?  I vaguely recall that it blocks incoming icmp by default

Comment: I have never tampered with the windows firewall so I suppose that I had the default settings before the addition of my custom rules.

Comment: Some Windows system can block icmp at default, I got this problem a few times.